# Differential equation with variable coefficients

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, special-functions, substitution

I saw this differential equation somewhere $$y''+xy=0$$ 
it was solved using the substitution $$y=x^\alpha u$$
where $\alpha$, is a constant. My question is how can we substitute for $y$ with an expression containing the independent variable $x$? Is it because we put $x$ raised to power $\alpha$ so in that case we haven't made any assumptions about $y$ depending on $x$, as $\alpha$ may be any value depending on the solution itself?

Comment: The function $y$ depends on $x$. We just assumed that there is a function $u(x)$ which makes the equation $y(x)=x^\alpha u(x)$ valid. This is allowed

Comment: See also [Airy function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Airy_function) which will tell you a lot about the solution to this equation